# Import csv file to postgres db table (with check constraint) such that import should import all the rows which are passing the check constraint

Tags: postgresql, csv

I have a table say `test_table(id integer check (id>10 and id<100))`.
So what should I do to import all the rows that are in the range of the above mentioned check from CSV file.

Comment: Well, "filter out the bad ids" is the answer to the question you asked. Perhaps if you said how you are importing them a more useful answer could be given. Are you using a scripting language, data-loader, psql with \copy?

Comment: Am using copy for importing..

Answer (score 0):

The typical way to import a table from csv would be to use `copy`.  `copy` stops at the first error, so that command is not going to work.

I would suggest that you insert the data into a staging table, the load the results from the staging table into the final table.  You can drop the staging table when you are done.

Comment: Thanks for your answer... Actually thats what im doing now.. :) But actually my tables are very big, So for one insert itself i have to make space for twice the size of the table